# Avoid empty file creation

Tags: perl

I want to split the large file in to small files by splitting at the specific line with the help of regex. Any help?
My code doing the job but it also creating a empty file.

```
#!/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2

open( INFILE, 'test.txt' );
@lines = <INFILE>;
$file  = "outfile";
for ( $j = 0; $j <= $#lines; $j++ ) {
    open( OUTFILE, ">", $file . $j );
    $file_name = $file . $j;
    #print "file is $file_name\n";
    $i = 0;
    while (@lines) {
        $_ = shift @lines;
        chomp;
        $i++;
        if ( $_ =~ /^###\s*(.*)\s*###/ && $i > 1 ) {
            unshift @lines, "$_\n";
            print "$filename\n";
            last;
        }
        print OUTFILE "$_\n";
    }
    close(OUTFILE);
}
close(INFILE);
```

My input file contains :

```
------------- 
### abcd hdkjfkdj #### 
body 1 dsjklsjdfskl 
### zyz fhid ### 
abcdksdsd djnfkldsfmnsldk ;lkjfkl 
---------------------------
```

it is creating 3 outfiles called `outfile0`,`outfile1`,`outfile2`. but `outfile0` is empty I want to avoid this.

Comment: Well how'd we know what's wrong with your code until we see it?

Comment: I am trying to add my code but the system is not allowing me.

Comment: Which system? You mean StackOverflow? Just edit your post and paste the code.

Comment: Error: Only one additional @ user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified.

Comment: Sorry we can't help unless you explain your problem in detail with the code.

Comment: #!/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
open (INFILE, 'test.txt');@lines = <INFILE>;
$file = "outfile";
for ($j = 0; $j<=$#lines; $j++) {
open (OUTFILE, ">", $file.$j);
$file_name = $file.$j;
#print "file is $file_name\n";
$i=0;
while (@lines) {
$_ = shift @lines;
chomp;
$i++;
if ($_ =~ /^###\s*(.*)\s*###/ && $i > 1) {
unshift @lines, "$_\n";
print "$filename\n";
last
}
print OUTFILE "$_\n";
}
close (OUTFILE);
}
close (INFILE);

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to add it in my main post.

Comment: My input file is :


-------------
### abcd hdkjfkdj ####
body 1
dsjklsjdfskl

### zyz fhid ###

abcdksdsd

djnfkldsfmnsldk  ;lkjfkl

---------------------------

it is creating 3 outfiles called

outfile0,outfile1,outfile2.

but outfile0 is empty i want to avoid this.

Comment: I added your code snippet from comment. Please edit those if you feel anything is copied in wrong way

Comment: it is correct Samiron, thank you.

Comment: The code which you have shared will not create an empty file. I tried your code and here is the result: http://i.imgur.com/vSRVYqx.jpg BTW there are a lot of errors in your code. You should `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 3):

The way to fix it is to open the file only in response to the line being found.  Your program will open a new file regardless and that's why it has an empty output file

Here is a rewrite that works.  I've also removed the temporary @lines array

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;

open(my $file,"<", "test.txt") || die $!;
my $counter=1;
my $out;

while(<$file>) {
  if (/###\s*(.*)\s*###/) { 
    open($out, ">", "outfile$counter") || warn "outfile$counter $!";
    $counter++;
  }
  print $out $_ if $out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, can we rename oufile0...etc.. or name the generated files with the eregex- $1 value in the if condition?

if (/###\s*(.*)\s*###/) { 

in the above (.*)-->$1 can we name the file with $1 value?

Comment: I have got the file naming as well, one more doubt. can we use multiple conditions in splitting function?

Comment: can you use $1 to name the file?  Yes  "can we use multiple conditions"?  Not sure what you mean.  Make another SO question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the material between the `###` blocks as file titles, you can set the file name when you're doing the pattern match on the lines with `###` blocks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'my_file.txt' or die "Could not open file: $!";

# initialise a variable that will hold the output file handle
my $out;
while (<$fh>) {
    # capture the title between the # signs
    if (/##+ (.*?) ##+/) {
        open $out, '>', $1.".txt" or die "Could not create file $1.txt: $!";
    }
    elsif ($out) {
        print $out $_;
    }
    else {
        # if $out is not set, we haven't yet encountered a title block
        warn "Error: line found with no title block: $_";
    }
}
```

Sample input:

```
Text files containing their own name
### questions-1 ####
Why are a motorcycle's front brakes more effective than back?
Is it possible to make a gradient follow a path in Illustrator?
Text files containing their own name
### questions-2 ###
Why does Yoda mourn the Jedi after order 66 is executed?
what are the standard gui elements called?
Flybe just cancelled my return flight. Will they refund that part of the trip?
### questions-3 ###
Merge two arrays of ElementModels?
Is this set open or closed?
```

Output: three files, `questions-1.txt`, `questions-2.txt`, `questions-3.txt`, containing the appropriate lines. e.g. questions-1.txt:

```
Why are a motorcycle's front brakes more effective than back?
Is it possible to make a gradient follow a path in Illustrator?
Text files containing their own name
```

You haven't stated whether you want the `###` lines in the output or not, so I've left them off.

Depending on what OS you're on and what your potential file names contain, you may want to filter them and replace special characters with an underscore (or just remove the special characters).